# How many pairs of polynomials $(U,V)\in \Bbb Z[x]^2$ such that $P=U^2+V^2$ for a given polynomial with integer coefficients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

This question is no more than curiosity question.

For integers we know that a positive integer $n$ is a sum of two squares if and only if for any prime $p$ such that $p\equiv 3 \mod 4$ we have $v_p(n)$ is even, and we know also that the number of possible representations $n=x^2+y^2$ is $r_2(n)=4(d_{4,1}(n)-d_{4,3}(n))$.

My question asks for similar results for other rings $\Bbb Z[x]$ for example

> Given a polynomial $P\in \Bbb Z[x]$ how many pairs of polynomials $(U,V)\in \Bbb Z[x]^2$ such that $P=U^2+V^2$

This can be interpreted in $\Bbb Z[i][x]$ as a factorization of $P$ but the problem is how many divisors $P$ in $\Bbb Z[i][x]$ may have, for example:
$x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)=(x^2+1)1 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $P(x) = U(x)^2+V(x)^2$ is the same as writing $P(x) = (U(x)+i V(x))(U(x)-i V(x))$. Factor $P(x)$ over the UFD $\mathbb{Z}[i][x]$ as 
$$i^s (1+i)^t \prod_i \pi_i^{a_i} \overline{\pi_i}^{a_i} \prod_j q_j^{b_j} \prod_k \phi_k(x)^{c_k} \overline{\phi_k}(x)^{c_k} \prod_{\ell} g_{\ell}(x)^{d_{\ell}} \quad (\ast)$$
where

- the $\pi_i$ are Gaussian primes not in $\mathbb{Z} \cup i \mathbb{Z}$
- the $q_j$ are integer primes
- the $\phi_k(x)$ are primitive irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[i][x]$ not in $\mathbb{Z}[x] \cup i \mathbb{Z}[x]$
- the $g_{\ell}(x)$ are primitive irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

In order to write $P(x)$ as $(U(x)+iV(x))(U(x)-iV(x))$, we have to split the factors in $(\ast)$ into two complex conjugate sets. In order to be able to do this at all, we have the following necessary conditions:

- The $b_j$ and $d_{\ell}$ are all even. Note that this forces all real roots of $P$ to have even multiplicity, so $P(x) \geq 0$ or $P(x) \leq 0$ for all $x$.
- $2s+t \equiv 0 \bmod 8$. In the context of the previous condition, this is equivalent to $P(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$.

Assuming these conditions hold, I get that there are
$$4 \prod_i (a_i+1) \prod_{k} (c_k+1)$$
different ways to factor $P(x) = (U(x)+iV(x))(U(x) - i V(x))$. The factor of $4$ comes from choosing which power of $i$ to put on each factor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your effort,but I still the formula must include the $b_j$ for instance $x^2+1= x^2+1^2=(-x)^2+1=x^2+(-1)^2=(-x)^2+(-1)^2$ this is the only polynomials . the formula gives us $4*(1+1)=8$ so did I miss somthing? in the same way if we just multiply by $2$ we get $2(x^2+1)=(x-1)^2+(x+1)^2$ which still the same gives us $4$ ways and if we multiply by $3$ we don't have any, because $3(x^2+1)=?$. In the bigining I was just asking for the case $x^n+a^n$ and I can't find a formula because there are a lot of parameters , every case is special

Comment: I don't think I follow your example. $x^2+1 = (x+i)(x-i)$ so we have $c_1=1$ and all the $a$, $b$ and $d$ vanish. So the formula gives $8$, which is correct (four expressions of the form $(\pm x)^2+(\pm 1)^2$ and four of the form $(\pm 1)^2+(\pm x)^2$).

Comment: This is analogous to the formula $4 \prod (a_i+1)$ in the ordinary integer case. For example, $5$ is a sum of two squares in $8$ ways. And the number of ways to write $5$ as a sum of two squares is the same as $45$, so we don't need to keep track of what power of the primes $3 \bmod 4$ we use, expect to impose that they are even powers.

Comment: Thanks you for this useful answer, I will try to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are similar results for polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. The first observations is, that we need $P(x)\ge 0$ in order to represent $P$ as the sum of two squares in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. There is the following result of [Davenport, Lewis and Schinzel](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=163880), which reduces the question to sum of  two squares in $\mathbb{Z}$.

> If $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients such that every
>   arithmetic progression contains an integer $n$ for which $f(n)$ is a
>   sum of two squares, then $f(x) = u(x)^2+v(x)^2$ where $u$ and $v$ are
>   polynomials with integer coefficients.

Comment: yes this is avery interesting result, how about the estmation of the number of decompositions

Comment: I don't know a formula like for integers (the number is often just zero , e.g., if $P$ is not positive), but upper bounds should follow from Schinzel's results.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use $Schinzel's results$ and I'm studyng some interesting examples like $P=x^n+a^n$ which seems to be very difficult, so that's what I'm offering the bounty and if there is an upper bound or lower bound it would be an interesting result